SQL group multiple transactions into one based on time between (LAG function?)
I am working with forecourt machine data (e.g. jet wash / air) that accepts coins to operate. Each coin is a transaction line. However, I want to group up multiple rows into one 'transaction' if the coins went in less than 3 minutes apart.
I thought to use LAG function to tell me if the previous transaction is less than 3 minutes ago, but now I'm not sure how to group up the multiple rows (as it could be 1 previous row or many previous rows).
How would you tackle this problem?
Here's what I tried so far:
select  t1.*,
        datediff(second, PreviousVendDateTime, VendDateTime) as SecondsDiff
        case when datediff(second, PreviousVendDateTime, VendDateTime) < 360 then 1 else 0 end as                          SameTransaction
from 
        (select       mct.TransactionID,
                      mct.MachineID,
                      mct.VendDateTime,
                      mct.Amount,
                      lag(mct.VendDateTime, 1)
                        over(partition by mct.MachineID order by mct.VendDateTime as PreviousVendDateTime
        from          Machines as m
        join          MCI_CashTrans as mct
        on            mct.MachineID = m.MachineID
        and           mct.MachineSerial = m.MachineSerial
        join          Account as a
        on            m.AccountNo = a.AccountNo
        join          MachineType as mt
        on            m.MachineTypeID = mt.MachineTypeID) as t1
order by MachineID, VendDateTime


And a sample of the results:



TransactionID
MachineID
VendDateTime
Amount
PreviousVendDateTime
SecondsDiff
SameTransaction




2518059219
777
2023-06-01 19:01:54
1.00
2023-06-01 18:53:58
476
0


2519059559
777
2023-06-01 19:02:09
1.00
2023-06-01 19:01:54
15
1


2518357022
777
2023-06-01 21:20:41
1.00
2023-06-01 19:02:09
8312
0


2518362875
777
2023-06-01 21:23:01
1.00
2023-06-01 21:20:41
140
1


2518369251
777
2023-06-01 21:29:12
1.00
2023-06-01 21:23:01
371
0


2518369599
777
2023-06-01 21:29:38
1.00
2023-06-01 21:29:12
26
1


2518369737
777
2023-06-01 21:29:51
1.00
2023-06-01 21:29:38
13
1


2518369894
777
2023-06-01 21:30:04
0.50
2023-06-01 21:29:51
13
1


2518370027
777
2023-06-01 21:30:17
0.50
2023-06-01 21:30:04
13
1


2518370171
777
2023-06-01 21:30:31
1.00
2023-06-01 21:30:17
14
1


2518370338
777
2023-06-01 21:30:44
1.00
2023-06-01 21:30:31
13
1


2518404884
777
2023-06-01 21:46:11
1.00
2023-06-01 21:30:44
927
0




For example, you have a million transactions, each with one second between them, what should the result of grouping such a set look like? Because you can group 1,2,3 or 2,3,4, etc.

When SameTransaction goes back to 0 I want it to start grouping again. It's like I need a for loop or something.

Please provide sample data from all tables involved along with expected result from that data. And tag the rdbms you are using.

A [mcve] us supposed to include both sample table data and the matching result. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Revert the case to get a start of transaction flag and to compute a tranNo as a sum of flags
with starts as(
    select  t1.*,
            datediff(second, PreviousVendDateTime, VendDateTime) as SecondsDiff
            case when datediff(second, PreviousVendDateTime, VendDateTime) >= 360 then 1 else 0 end as tranStart
    from 
            (select       mct.TransactionID,
                          mct.MachineID,
                          mct.VendDateTime,
                          mct.Amount,
                          lag(mct.VendDateTime, 1)
                            over(partition by mct.MachineID order by mct.VendDateTime as PreviousVendDateTime
            from          Machines as m
            join          MCI_CashTrans as mct
            on            mct.MachineID = m.MachineID
            and           mct.MachineSerial = m.MachineSerial
            join          Account as a
            on            m.AccountNo = a.AccountNo
            join          MachineType as mt
            on            m.MachineTypeID = mt.MachineTypeID) as t1
)
select starts.*,
       sum(tranStart) over(partition by MachineID order by VendDateTime) trnNo

Then you can group rows by MachineID and trnNo

I'd give this a try;
In a single statement, use 'with' and lag / lead window functions to produce

a cte A with machineId, timeStamp, isStart partitioned by machineId, sorted by timestamp where isStart 1 indicates is more than 3 mins ahead of previous in partition, otherwise = 0

a cte B = subset of A where isStart = 1 partitioned by machineId, sorted by timestamp with nextStart = value for timestamp of subsequent row in partition.

a join between your main data D and B on D.machineId = B.machineID and D.timestamp >= B.timestamp and
D.timestamp < B.nextStart, grouped by machineId, B.timestamp.


If there's a lot of data I might use temp tables and indexing or even use an alternative to SQL.
